# How to get/set the iOS "preferred language" from a RN app?

Tags: ios, react-native, localization

We are developing a React Native app supporting three languages. For various reasons, we must have specific language selection logic in the app and a language selector within the app.

In iOS 13 there is a new "Preferred language" selector in the system settings for the app. We would want the in-app language selector to change the preferred language, and conversely that the user could also change their language in the system settings.

How can I read/write the iOS "Preferred language" in a React Native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred language setting cannot be explicitly fetched or set. Changing the preferred language appears to the app just like the whole system language is changed to the selected language.

We implemented in-app language selection so that the app uses the system language until the user explicitly changes the language in the app. Thus, if the user changes the preferred language, the app language changes. After the user changes the language in the app, the preferred language no longer matches the app language and changing it has no impact. (The user knows where to find the language setting after they have changed it once.)

Answer (score 1):

You simply add it to Xcode (see image).
Then grab the languages in your app by using [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize)

[image: xcode image]